# Python to XML get multiple child

Tags: python, xml, dataframe

I am working with python, I need to move my xml to csv file, right now I have an issue with the tag "customfields" can be more than one tag with that name and inside each customfields tag I need to add fieldName and Value.

My code works but for fieldName and Value variables only store the last tag captured.

My result should be like these

| ID. | abbreviation | active | address. | fieldName | value. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2424 | X1C-02220 | true. | my address | Company |  |
| 2424 | X1C-02220 | true. | my address | Org | Tiber |

But now is looking like these

| ID. | abbreviation | active | address. | fieldName | value. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2424 | X1C-02220 | true. | my address | Org | Tiber |

This is my xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:getListResponse xmlns:ns1="http://service.web.propertyware.realpage.com" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <getListReturn xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[824]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
            <getListReturn xmlns:ns2="urn:PWServices" xsi:type="ns2:Unit">
               <ID xsi:type="xsd:long">2424</ID>
               <abbreviation xsi:type="xsd:string">X1C-02220</abbreviation>
               <active xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</active>
               <address xsi:type="xsd:string">my address</address>
               <customFields soapenc:arrayType="ns2:CustomField[129]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
                  <customFields xsi:type="ns2:CustomField">
                     <ID xsi:type="xsd:long">0</ID>
                     <clientData xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xsi:nil="true"/>
                     <dataType xsi:type="xsd:string">Text</dataType>
                     <definitionID xsi:type="xsd:long">0</definitionID>
                     <fieldName xsi:type="xsd:string">Company</fieldName>
                     <value xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                  </customFields>
                    <customFields xsi:type="ns2:CustomField">
                     <fieldName xsi:type="xsd:string">Org</fieldName>
                     <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Tiber</value>
                  </customFields>
                 </customFields>
            </getListReturn>
         </getListReturn>
      </ns1:getListResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my code

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import csv

root = ET.parse('build.xml')  # replace file name

cols = ["ID","abbreviation","active","address"
        ,"fieldName","value"
        ]
rows = []


branches = root.findall('.//getListReturn/getListReturn')
for branch in branches:
    ID = branch.find('ID').text
    abbreviation= branch.find('abbreviation').text
    active= branch.find('active').text
    address= branch.find('address').text
    customs=branch.findall('.//customFields/customFields')
    for custom in customs:
        fieldName=custom.find('fieldName').text
        value=custom.find('value').text
    
    rows.append({"ID":ID,"abbreviation":abbreviation,
                 "active":active,"address":address
                 ,"fieldName":fieldName,"value":value
                })
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

How to store all the data from "customfields" tag?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply indent the `rows.append` inside the inner loop to capture all information under child element:

```py
...
    for custom in customs:
        fieldName = custom.find('fieldName').text
        value = custom.find('value').text
    
        rows.append({
            "ID":ID, "abbreviation":abbreviation,
            "active":active, "address":address,
            "fieldName":fieldName, "value":value
        })
```

Consider also, list/dict comprehensions with a [dictionary merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/1422451) to combine both parent/child levels:

```py
root = ET.parse('build.xml')

rows = [
    {
     **{
        "ID": branch.find('abbreviation').text,
        "abbreviation": branch.find('abbreviation').text,
        "active": branch.find('active').text,
        "address": branch.find('address').text,
        "fieldName":fieldName,
        "value":value
      },
     **{
        "fieldName": custom.find('fieldName').text,
        "value": custom.find('value').text
     }
    }
    
    for branch in root.findall('.//getListReturn/getListReturn')
    for custom in branch.findall('.//customFields/customFields')
]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```